# Merge 2 arrays into 1 array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key, array-merge

I've 2 arrays:

```
{"1":"red"}
{"1":"green","2":"red"}
```

It should remove 1 = green and replace it with 1 = red. Key 2 must simply remain.

So, I want an array like this:

```
{"1":"red","2":"red"}
```

How can I do that in PHP?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: It's already fixed. The array 1 + array 2 fixed it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the operator `+` :

```
$a = [1 => "red"] ;
$b = [1 => "green", 2 => "red"] ;
print_r($a + $b) ;
```

Outputs :

```
Array
(
    [1] => red
    [2] => red
)
```

> From [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) :
>   The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored.